# Build simple job trigger in Quartz.net 2.1.x

Tags: quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

What is the easiest way to build trigger for a job with given interval as TimeSpan and specified DayOfWeek in 2.1.x versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to build a simple Trigger ? Simple Triggers are prone to DST issues. Make a CRON Trigger using a CRON expression and specify an end time so that the job expires.

Comment: yes, I used to make triggers using crone expressions, but situation above (just set dayOfWeek and interval in TimeSpan type) sounds like quite easy, and i suppouse there is better way to build such trigger than to parse TimeSpan for seconds, minutes and hours, and generate cron expression. Not necessary it should be simple trigger.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to set Start time in SimpleTrigger and then set repeat Interval as 7*24*60*60, this will do the trick. However you will run into issues when DST becomes active/deactive.

Answer (score 1):

Geek is very right, cron expression may be a bit tricky at first look but they are flawless.

As for quartz, cron expression for "Day of week" can be like: `0 0 8 ? * 1 *` Would mean 8 AM every Monday

You better refer to: [Quartz CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)